# How can I run the same test for X times in parallel execution?

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I have a simple test

```
@Test
public void searchInGoogle() {
    final String searchKey = "TestNG";
    System.out.println("Search " + searchKey + " in google");
    driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    System.out.println("Enter " + searchKey);
    element.sendKeys(searchKey);
    System.out.println("submit");
    element.submit();
    System.out.println("Got " + searchKey + " results");
}
```

I want to run it 10 times in parallel, 
Meaning 10 chrome windows will open parallel and execute the same test.

Please help , I've seen things similar but not exactly this.

Thanks !

Comment: The question is of general relevance: how to execute a test method repeatedly while concurrently w.r.t. itself (which means not necessarily concurrently w.r.t. other test methods). However, the question is posed with a concrete test scenario in mind. Consider generalizing the question; that is, reformulate it such that the test scenario where you want to open 10 Web browser windows in parallel becomes an *example* of where one would want to execute a test method concurrently.

Answer (score 4):

In JUnit 5 you can use [@RepeatedTest](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-repeated-tests) to run a single test case multiple times.

Though presently still an experimental feature, you can also specify that tests should be executed [in parallel](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parallel-execution), by setting the `junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled` to true as part of your [JUnit 5 configuration settings](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-config-params).

Your code would then look as follows:

```
@Execution(CONCURRENT)
class GoogleSearchTest {

  import ...

  @RepeatedTest(10)
  public void searchInGoogle() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but it didn't happen parallel , but 1 by one.  Here is pic to demonstrate http://prntscr.com/nhpfb3

Comment: @Spartacus The fact that the test method ran sequentially (as indicated by the linked screenshot) might be caused by the IDE used. It might use its own `TestEngine` (i.e., not JUnit's *Jupiter* test engine) and might therefore simply not support concurrent execution of test methods, or it might need to be configured differently (i.e. it might not consider `junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled` but another configuration setting). You should check that. You could also try to execute your test from the command line where *Jupiter* should be used by default.

Answer (score 0):

This is old so I'm sure you've found a solution by now, but could you not just move the test logic into a method and go:

```
IntStream.range(1, 10).parallel().forEach(this::myTestMethod);
```